# How to make custom settings data available globally in Yii 2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm creating an application which stores some settings in the database and ideally it would be good to load these settings during bootstrapping and make them available via an object globally.

Can this be done and added to `Yii::$app->params` somehow?

Such as you can create a class and return the details as an array or object instance?

Comment: You can use session.

Comment: Since ```Yii::$app->params``` is just an array, you can add values in it even later using something like ```Yii::$app->params['someSetting'] = 'value';```. But i'm not sure exactly where it would make most sense to do something like this. Would love to hear some suggestions about best practices regarding that.

Comment: @Kshitiz That would be ok except for the fact that sessions can get destroyed (say if the user is logged out) and I don't want that happening with this.

Comment: @Tahir Yeah...... just trying to find out the best place to load the settings early on is and how to do it.

Comment: @Tahir I found out how to do it and posted an answer so I thought I would let you know as you sounded interested. :)

Comment: It's very good question, thank you!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to do it.

Basically you have to implement the [bootstrapInterface](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-bootstrapinterface.html), an example below for my situation.

Set the path to your class that implements the interface:

**app/config/web.php:**

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => [
                    'log',
                    'app\base\Settings',
    ],
    //.............
];
```

So I have placed a class called `Settings.php` at the location: `app\base\Settings.php`.

Then this is my `Settings.php` file:

```
namespace app\base;

use Yii;
use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

/*
/* The base class that you use to retrieve the settings from the database
*/

class settings implements BootstrapInterface {

    private $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = Yii::$app->db;
    }

    /**
    * Bootstrap method to be called during application bootstrap stage.
    * Loads all the settings into the Yii::$app->params array
    * @param Application $app the application currently running
    */

    public function bootstrap($app) {

        // Get settings from database
        $sql = $this->db->createCommand("SELECT setting_name,setting_value FROM settings");
        $settings = $sql->queryAll();

        // Now let's load the settings into the global params array

        foreach ($settings as $key => $val) {
            Yii::$app->params['settings'][$val['setting_name']] = $val['setting_value'];
        }

    }

}
```

I can now access my settings via `Yii:$app->params['settings']` globally.

Extra information on other ways to bootstrap stuff [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap).

Comment: Now thats more like Yii way of doing it. thanks for posting the answer.

Comment: i tried this using advanced template but i get `Function name must be a string`

Comment: @bonez Perhaps you could post a question with your code whilst referencing this answer.

Comment: fixed. i had to remove `()` after app. im trying to move my yii 1.x app to 2.x

Comment: how do i  make these settings or other available before user logs in. currently you have to log in to have it available?

Comment: @bonez Have you read this page: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#bootstrap -- You shouldn't have to log in at all. Perhaps create another question so you can show your code.

Comment: for yii2 advance templte if i use it in backend, is it available in common ,frontend folder ?? or i re-do the same in common and frontend??

Comment: @VinodC I'm not too familiar with the advanced template, however, you should be able to access it anywhere if it is all apart of the same `application`.

Comment: @Brett thank yo, the answer its really nice.
Please do you know if there is a way to add cache managment at this point? The idea would be to load the table ones and not every or all the time.

Comment: @PabloPalacios Have you looked at Yii's documentation on [caching management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-caching-overview.html)? However if it's for caching a database call then check out my question [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/72908-how-does-the-caching-dbdependency-work-exactly/page__p__304623__fromsearch__1) for your consideration.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me on that direction, now I am fully caching this settings.

Comment: @moplin No worries :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party, but there is a much easier way to do this.

```
$config = [
    'id' => 'basic',
    'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
    'bootstrap' => [
                    'log',
    ],
    //.............
    'params' = [
        'adminEmail' => 'admin@example.com',
        'defaultImage' => '/images/default.jpg',
        'noReplyEmail' => 'noreply@example.com'
    ],
];
```

Now you can simply access those variables with the following syntax

```
$adminEmail = \Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'];
```

Comment: That's all well and good if you are setting the values manually; but the point of this question was setting them dynamically via another script. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is override init() method in the baseController.

```
class BaseController extends Controller{...    
public function init()
    {    
            if(Yii::$app->cache->get('app_config'))
        {
            $config = Yii::$app->cache->get('app_config');
            foreach ($config as $key => $val)
            {
                Yii::$app->params['settings'][$key] = $val->value;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $config = Config::find()->all();
            $config = ArrayHelper::regroup_table($config, 'name', true);
            Yii::$app->cache->set('app_config', $config, 600);

            foreach ($config as $key => $val)
            {
                Yii::$app->params['settings'][$key] = $val->value;
            }
        }
}
....}
```

It`s up to you. I used to do this method in Yii1 but now I would prefer bootstrap method