# How to make custom settings data available globally in Yii 2 based on the user session details?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

This similar question have been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778477/how-to-make-custom-settings-data-available-globally-in-yii-2) 
I'm creating an application which stores some settings in the database and ideally it would be good to load these settings during bootstrapping and make them available via an object globally.

Can this be done and added to Yii::$app->params somehow?

Such as you can create a class and return the details as an array or object instance?
But in my case i have different settings for different users and want to be able to add config details such as language, preferred date format etc after a user has logged it, based on the user sittings option

Comment: you can configure `Yii::$app->params`  dinamically

Comment: please any idea how @scaisEdge

Comment: extend your login assigning the value  you need ..

Comment: this is what i tried doing 

public function afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration){
        parent::afterLogin($identity, $cookieBased, $duration);
  
       
       Yii::$app->params['settings'] = 'some value';
   }
but it did not take effect after login

Comment: Looking  to your approach  seems that is better a solution based  on session setting  .. as suggested  by @ZbigniewSzczęsny..  ..

Comment: if i understand correctly these settings are saved in the database against the `user_id` for every user and you want these settings to be available after a user has logged in, why do you want to store them into `params` when they are available through the `Yii::$app->user->identity` if you have defined you relations properly inside your `User` model

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit mysterious. Generally,

```
Yii::$app->params
```

is a table of parameters attached to an application singleton.

But there is also a

```
Yii::$app->session
```

and ou may use this object to set and get user's session specific data and this way make them available "globally" withing an application.

Have a read:

http://www.bsourcecode.com/yiiframework2/session-handling-in-yii-framework-2-0/

I hope this might be helpful!

Comment: i fully understand how Yii::$app->session work , the issue i have is , i would like to set Yii::$app->params['settings'] inside of afterLogin() method

Comment: But... Why actually? What is the purpose to change application configuration params after login?