# How to change the params in yii2?

Tags: configuration, yii2

I added a parameter called ref_times in `backend/config/params.php` and I'm trying to set a new value for it each time the admin changes it. I can call it and get its value on views but I can't change it.

I tried changing by getting the user post request but its not working.

```
if($post['delivery_free']){
    $free =  $post['delivery_free'];
    Yii::$app->params['ref_times'] = $free;
}
```

How can I set a new value? I cant seem to find any documentation about it.... this is really frustrating..

Comment: what do you mean with  .. "not working."  .. you have an error ?   .. unexpected  .result ?.. are you sure you need an application param  . and not a session param ???  trye explain better your needs

Comment: you cant do that if the param `ref_time` is declared in the `params` file and will reload the default value  at every request . you can declare a new param though, or bind your custom params at the time of bootstrap from database or a file https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27778477/how-to-make-custom-settings-data-available-globally-in-yii-2 you might have to explain what are you trying to achieve that forced you into implemnting this logic, maybe we can find anotther way?

Comment: I added a parameter called ref_times in backend/config/params.php and I'm trying to set a new value for it each time the admin changes it.

Comment: move it to session or database table column rather than keeping in the params file

Comment: Ref_times refers to the number of times that the user can get free delivery because they used a referral code when registration. The number of times is set to all codes and isn't configured for each one. The admin is the only user that could change it. Hence why I used a config file to set it up. Make a new table for it is not really needed or a good way to handle it. I'm new to Yii2 and I find it hard to get information that I need...

Comment: why not ? if yo track the free deliveries against the user ids in the table along with the number of times he is awarded, maybe i still didnt understood your requirments but i think using params file isnt a good idea as the params work as constants or intead of using **hardcoded numbers and strings everywhere in your code** you cant change the file and every time you make a request your params are reloaded from that file.

Comment: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications#params

Comment: Because I don't need to track the user_ids. Since I only count the amount of successful orders that the user is using. So if a user ordered 15 times and I had ref_times as 10, then the user wont get a free delivery. If I put it inside a database, I'd have to make a connection and get a query.. which isn't really needed for that case. But if things stay like this, I'll just go ahead with the database...

Comment: if you need to compare only then why are you overriding it in this line `Yii::$app->params['ref_times'] = $free;` that is what i am trying to tell, when you do that you can get the new value only for that request, means after that line if you access the value it will show you the new value,but you cant expect it to be changed for all the requests or in the `params.php` file.

Comment: I see.. Thanks for explaining. I'm gonna make a table for it.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can't change it, my friend. Change the logic instead. Move your controll inside the login section or somewhere else. Look also into theme section but a well structured db can save you tons of useless code

-after login -> check if is admin (by passing a value to confirm the identity)

-if admin do something